# HTML <SELECT> Drop menu, show multiple but choose only one at time

Tags: html

Is there a way to have a `select` drop menu showing `multiple` `option`s at ago but the user can only `click` on a single Item... How to restrict them from highlighting all options at ago even though they can see all the options?

**Example**

```html
<form action="">
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<strong>They Should NOT Highlight or select more than one option at a go!!</strong>
```

I want the user to NEVER Highlight all `option`s at ago because that will `submit` all options to the `SERVER-SIDE Script` and Err.

**See it in action here:**
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

Go to that link and try to highlight all options and `Submit` the query... You'll see all `option`s are submitted. How to prevent that **multiple highlighting** even when they click `CTRL`+`option` after `option`?

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Thanks but I want all `option`s to be displayed initially.... But only `select` 1 `option` at at time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `multiple` set a `size` to it

```
<form action="">
<select name="cars" size="4">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: THAT IS ABSOLUTELY AMAZING!!!!!.... I never thought of that since Birth.. Thank you a million times

Answer (score 0):

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gobxnvuf/)

#### HTML:

```
<form action="">
  <select name="cars" visible="volvo">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want all `option`s to be displayed initially.... But only `select` 1 `option` at at time

Answer (score 0):

From:
`<select name="cars" multiple>`
To:
`<select name="cars">`

Comment: Thanks but I want all `option`s to be displayed initially.... But only `select` 1 `option` at at time